# Rewrite URL to subdomain in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I'm having trouble understanding how to combine a redirect with an URL rewrite in HAProxy. Specifically I have this URL

```
https://www.example.com/en/blog
```

that I need to rewrite to

```
http://blog.example.com/en
```

So I need to change the host and scheme, and remove the `/blog` path prefix in one step.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by combining `reqrep` and `redirect` like so

```
use_backend website-blog if { path_reg \/?(.*)\/blog }

backend website-blog
  reqrep        ^([^\ :]*)\ \/?(.*)\/blog\/?(.*)    \1\ /\2/\3
  redirect      prefix http://blog.example.com    code 301
```